# Should SSO include authorization or only authentication?

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on

So the idea that we're going to develop our SSO, and it's going to be used for authentication in multiple web applications so users can use one account when signing in to any of these apps.

We had the discussion if we should include the authorization inside the SSO or each application should store the authorization (roles/permissions) separately.

Here're some pints to consider:

- Authorization isn't shared between applications, each one has
  a different set of roles and permissions so in case we're going to
  store roles inside the SSO, it has to be done per application.
- If we're going to store users roles/permissions in SSO, we need to set up API end
  points to fetch these data or sync them to each application?
- Is it considered positive or negative to have centralized authorization?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standards based way to provide authorization information by using standardised SSO protocols. SSO protocols allow to provide some information about the identity. Still you could provide some "entitlement string"

A standardised authorization protocol would be XACML.

Agreed, it's a bit complex but allows you to replace the centralised authorization service without changing the applications.

Personally I would try to use a standards-based approach because it may also safe you from vendor lock-in.
Personally I would also use a centralized approach as the 'client code' would be the similar for every application and management might be easier.

Comment: I like the idea of using standardized authorization but using one solution for authorization isn't possible because each application has its own roles so no roles will be shared across applications, for example one application could include edit role, other applications don't need this role, so each application will have its own logic/implementation on what users can do,